# Why Ionic 4 Framwork is not able to create an apk?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Hi I have used `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` this command for generating APK in Ionic 4 but I am getting error like this

[image]

This is the code in the **app.module.ts** as the error is shown here only.

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { CategoryPage } from '../pages/category/category';
import { CustomPage } from '../pages/custom/custom';
import { NewstuffPage } from '../pages/newstuff/newstuff'
import { ChinesePage } from '../pages/chinese/chinese';
import { ItalianPage } from '../pages/italian/italian';
import { MexicanPage } from '../pages/mexican/mexican';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CategoryPage,
    HomePage,
     CustomPage,
     ChinesePage,
      ItalianPage,
       MexicanPage,
       NewstuffPage,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    CategoryPage,
    HomePage,
     CustomPage,
     ChinesePage,
      ItalianPage,
       MexicanPage,
       NewstuffPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Output what I get in command prompt

```
C:\onlinefood>ionic cordova build android --prod --release
> ionic-app-scripts build --prod --target cordova --platform android
[16:18:00]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.0
[16:18:00]  build prod started ...
[16:18:00]  clean started ...
[16:18:00]  clean finished in 3 ms
[16:18:00]  copy started ...
[16:18:01]  deeplinks started ...
[16:18:01]  deeplinks finished in 71 ms
[16:18:01]  ngc started ...
[16:18:16]  typescript error
            Unexpected directive 'CategoryPage in C:/onlinefood/src/pages/category/category.ts' imported by the module
            'AppModule in C:/onlinefood/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

[16:18:16]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
[16:18:16]  Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
    at C:\onlinefood\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:237:55
    at step (C:\onlinefood\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:32:23)
    at Object.next (C:\onlinefood\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:13:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\onlinefood\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:4:58)
    at <anonymous>
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.

        ionic-app-scripts build --prod --target cordova --platform android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Thanks in advance for solving my problem.

Comment: Could you copy the error text in to your question instead of a screenshot? It helps people searching the problem later.

Comment: here is the problem i face

Comment: i have updated it

Comment: you missed a semi-colon after "import { NewstuffPage } from '../pages/newstuff/newstuff'"

Answer (score 0):

please try to update app-scripts by using command,

**npm install -g @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev**

then try to build again. i think this may help you.